# Delphi - Determining if Excel has Filters Enabled

Tags: excel, delphi, filter

Delphi Seattle, Excel 2013.  I have a Delphi application which modifies an existing Excel file.  If a sheet does NOT have row 1 Filtering enabled (aka the Filter dropdown boxes on each column), then I want to turn it on.  I know how to turn it on.  The issue is that the 'turn it on' is really a toggle, so I need to determine IF it is already on, which I can't seem to do. Applicable portions of code are:

```
var
 aws: ExcelWorksheet;
begin
...
 aws := oExcel.ActiveSheet as ExcelWorksheet;
 if aws.FilterMode[LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT] = False then
    aws.Cells.Item[1, 1].Rows.EntireRow.AutoFilter;
```

The issue is that my IF statement ALWAYS returns FALSE, even when row 1 has FILTER enabled.  I have tried using msoFalse instead of False, but then I get an 'Incompatible Type' error.  Note that I don't want to perform any filtering, I just want the dropdown to show to make things easier for the user.  I think my issue is that I am checking to see if a FILTER is actually implemented, as opposed to "am I showing the filter dropdown", but I don't know how else to check...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation for the `FilterMode` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.filtermode.aspx) says this:

> To determine whether filtering is currently enabled (that is, whether the filter drop-down arrows are displayed on the worksheet), use the [AutoFilterMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.autofiltermode.aspx) property.
>
> ...
>
> This property is **true** if the worksheet contains a filtered list in which there are hidden rows.

So use `AutoFilterMode` instead.

Comment: That was it... totally missed it.  Thanks!